# Is there a way to avoid the problem of jumping animation of slideDown() and SlideUp() in mobile resolution?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I want to display the subcategories of each category.
The action of displaying subcategories is different, i want to use hover in desktop resolution and click for mobile resolution
the problem is items of subcategories are not displaying in desktop resolution
and problem of jumping animation when we are not using the condition  if($(window).width() >1024)

i have tried to disable the code jquery script responsible for slideUp and down in mobile resolution

```
if($(window).width() >1024)  {
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('ul.r-list li').hover(function () {
      $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideDown()
    },function(){
      $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideUp() 
    }).find($(this).next()).hide()
});
}
```

but it doesn't works

expected result :

- no problem of jumping animation in mobile resolution
- displaying subcategories of each category in desktop resolution by using slideup and down works perfectly

actual result :

- items of subcategories are not displaying in desktop resolution
- problem of jumping animation when we are not using the condition if($(window).width() >1024)

```js
if($(window).width() >1024)  {
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('ul.r-list li').hover(function () {
      $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideDown()
    },function(){
      $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideUp() 
    }).find($(this).next()).hide()
});
}
$(document).ready(function(event){
    
    $('.r-list h1 span').click(function(){
        
      var $parent     = $(this).parent().parent();
      if($parent.hasClass('active')){
        $parent.removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-caret-down');
        $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-caret-right');
      } else {
        $parent.addClass('active');
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-caret-right');
        $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-caret-down');
      }
     
        
    });
    });
```

```css
ul.r-list li ul {
display:none;
list-style:none;

}
.fa 
{
  display:none;
 }

ul.r-list{
  list-style:none;
 }
 ul.r-list a{
   text-decoration:none;
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)
 {
  
 ul.r-list li h1 {
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
   
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
   
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    border-color: #eaeaea;
    color: #069;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
}

ul.r-list li a.sub-category {
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border-color: #eaeaea;
    color: #069;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
   
    
}

.fa {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 12px;
    
 }
 ul.r-list li {
    
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right:0;
    padding: 0;
   
}
ul.r-list li ul{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.r-list li.active ul{
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px 0 0 0;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="r-list">
 <li>
  <h1>
   <span class="collapse resp-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-lg"></i></span>
   <a class="category Parent" href="">Parent Category1</a>
   
  </h1>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a class="category sub-category children1" href="">sub Category1</a>
    
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="category sub-category children2" href="">sub Category2</a>
    
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="category sub-category children3" href="">sub Category3</a>
    
   </li>
  
   
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
<ul class="r-list">
 <li>
  <h1>
   <span class="collapse resp-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-lg"></i></span>
   <a class="category Parent" href="">Parent Category2</a>
   
  </h1>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a class="category sub-category children1" href="">sub Category1</a>
    
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="category sub-category children2" href="">sub Category2</a>
    
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="category sub-category children3" href="">sub Category3</a>
    
   </li>
  
   
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

[in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kq6580Lh/25/)

Comment: Your snippet is not working.

Comment: i have tested my snippet is working from my home if not can you check here : https://jsfiddle.net/kq6580Lh/25/